# How do grass seeds work?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

The description for grass seeds is very awkward:

> Grass that makes fodder for farm animals. Can harvest with sickle 2 days after sowing for 1 month.

I'm really not sure what this means. Does it mean I can harvest it ever 2 days after sowing it for a month? That I can harvest it only 2 days for a month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that 2 days after you sow the seeds in the ground, you can harvest it, and you don't need to water it. It comes back every day, and you don't have to do anything except harvest it.

It then grows for an entire month, so you can build up a nice stockpile (which is useful for when it likely will not grow in Winter).

If you have your cows outside near the grass field, they will graze on it.

Answer (score 3):

Grass regrows for about a month, before it stops.

Answer (score 3):

The wording is a little confusing.  It means that grass takes two days to grow, and for the next 31 days (one month), you can harvest it each and every day.  It doesn't need watering or anything.  Just harvesting.